# Get the attribute value of the first element?

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath, xquery

The following code tries to get the attribute `a` of the first node `y` in SQL Server.

```
declare @x xml = '<x><y a="1" /><y a="2" /></x>'

select @x.query('/x/y[1]/@a')

select @x.query('(/x/y/@a)[1]')
```

However, it got the error of

> Msg 6307, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>
> XML well-formedness check: Attribute cannot appear outside of element declaration. Rewrite your XQuery so it returns well-formed XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

```
select @x.query('data(/x/y[1]/@a)')
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand

**Example**

```
declare @x xml = '<x><y a="1" /><y a="2" /></x>'
select @x.value('x[1]/y[1]/@a','varchar(max)')
```

**Returns**

```
1
```